# Отображать вводимый в input текст в Div

Tags: javascript

Задача следующая:

Есть < Input Type='Text' >, в который вводится текст. Нужно, чтобы этот текст в режиме реального времени выводился в Div.
Если использовать стандартные события вроде OnChange - то текст обновится в Div только при перенесении фокуса мышки на другой элемент, то же самое с другими стандартными событиями. А нужно, чтобы выводился в тот же момент, когда и вводится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо `onChange` используйте `onKeyDown`

Comment: От вставки из буфера обмена это не спасёт(

Comment: Ну можно и oncontextmenu прикрутить...

Comment: еще можно добавить к onkeydown обработчик onkeyup (ctrl-v по крайней мере отработает)

Comment: помогло добавление таймера, уж не знаю правда, на сколько это правильно, но работает :)